# Rolling up multiple rows into a single row and column for SQL Server data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want is put the multilpe rows in a single row and column and I'm using MICROSOFT SQL Server. I tried the stuff command but I getting the error The multi-part identifier "" could not be bound. Please Help! Thanks

```
select a.CLAIMNO, e.INVNO, d.MSISDN, a.BATCHNO, b.CUSTOMER, b. PRODNO, 
b.INCENTIVE, b.QTY, b.STATUS, 
b.ROWNUM, b.RECEIVEDBY, b.RECEIVEDDATE, b.REMARKS, b.PESOVALUE
from CSPC_CLAIMHDR a
left join CSPC_CLAIMDTL b on a.PRFNO = b.PRFNO and a.CLAIMNO = b.CLAIMNO 
left join CSPC_CUSTOMERS c on c.CUSTNAME = b.CUSTOMER 
left join CSPC_PMACCOUNT d on d.CUSTCODE = c.CUSTCODE 
left join CSPC_INVOICEHDR e on e.CLAIMNO = a.CLAIMNO
where upper(a.PRFNO) = 'MOM--0108' and b.INCENTIVE not like '%POINTS%' and 
a.APPROVEDBY is not null order by b.CUSTOMER
```

this produces 
[Result][1]

```
CLAIMNO   INVNO 
618       SO202
618       SO213
618       SO932
618       SO133
618       SO873
658       SO123
658       SO877
```

and I want it to produce it like this below.

```
CLAIMNO   INVNO
618       SO202,SO213,SO932,SO133,SO873
658       SO123,SO877
```

Comment: MYsql does not have stuff or xml path are you trying to convert from sql server or is this incorrectly tagged?

Comment: I swapped your MySQL tag to sql-server because that error message is certainly from ms sql

Comment: sorry. it should be sql-server. btw, Caius Jard, yup. CSPC_CLAIMHDR contains a column called CLAIMNO.

Comment: I am just totally lost.  I see no `stuff()` in the question.  I see a result set with two columns but a table returning many columns.  Utterly confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement begins with

```
SELECT a.CLAIMNO, STUFF((...inner select query that aliases table a...))
```

It is the inner select query that aliases table a, not the outer one. A.claimno is not a thing/doesn’t exist by the time processing the sql gets to that outer level

Here is a simpler example:

```
select a.thing, (select a.otherthing from table a)
```

a.thing does not exist outside the brackets. These are valid

It isn’t really clear what you’re trying to do so I can’t advise on what you should do to achieve the result you want, I can only answer why you’re getting this error

You’d be better off removing the outer query, and the stuff call and **just posting up your inner query as a *new* question** with “this produces (paste results) and I want it to produce (create desired results), please help”

Comment: I edited the question. I want is put the INVNO in 1 row depending on the CLAIMNO of both CSPC_ClAIMHDR and CSPC_INVOICEHDR which has the same CLAIMNO.

Comment: The idea behind asking Question A, getting an answer to Question A and then raising Question B as a new question rather than editing Question A to be a completely different Question B, is that editing shifts the goalposts, invalidates the answers given and generally frustrates the people who've given answers/put effort into question A. As such, it's poor Q&A etiquette and should be avoided. Please copy your question, as it stands, to a new question, then revert the edits that completely changed Question A into Question B